# How to use non catkin package in catkin one

Tags: ros, catkin, octomap

i am trying to do some changes on [octomap](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap) source using [octomap_server](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping), so
first i have installed Octomap like `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-octomap`  and then i have cloned octomap_server package to my catkin workspace, the things goes fine where i can change the source of octomap_server and test my changes.

Now i need to change the source of octomap, so i cloned it, the problem i faced that the octomap is not a catkin package so i cant put it in the src folder.

How to force octomap_server to use my developed Octomap, how to make a link between catkin package and external non catkin package?

Comment: https://answers.ros.org/ might be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing from package server, try [cloning](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap) and building it with your changes.